# systemd service output to terminal/pty

Tags: 18.04, systemd, stdout

I am not able to figure out what option to pass in `StandardOutput=` for a
unit file (`.service`), where I want to show some messages on the connected terminal
from where the service is started! (`console`/`tty` doesn't seem to be what I want)

Maybe `/etc/systemd/system.conf`'s global default `DefaultStandardOutput=journal` can be changed, but I don't want to do that!
I am only interested in showing some progress/startup messages from my unit file 
(like `systemd-run -P`)

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.2

```
# systemd --version
systemd 237
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=

If I understand the question correctly you want the service outputs status to tty / console? Remember that when a service is started systemd take care of default file descriptors.

You can use a file to store the status and query it there.

Comment: No, that doesnt work! I already have `StandardOutput=file:/path/to/file` in all my units

Comment: you can make it over rsyslog https://serverfault.com/questions/381353/rsyslogd-any-way-to-get-around-the-number-of-local-facilities

Comment: No, these are debug logs and can be huge in volume. I don't want 20+ of my daemons to all write debug/trace logs via `syslog`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your script you want to run using systemd and add `| logger` to command you want output from to syslog:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ps aux | /usr/bin/grep gnome > /home/user/test/psoutput.txt
/usr/bin/date | logger
echo "This is terminal output" | logger
/usr/bin/date >> /home/user/test/psoutput.txt
```

Output of `$ sudo journalctl -u pstofile -f` is:

```
бер 09 13:33:42 lenovo systemd[1]: Started ps aux to file.
бер 09 13:33:42 lenovo root[8491]: понеділок, 9 березня 2020 13:33:42 +0200
бер 09 13:33:42 lenovo root[8493]: This is terminal output
бер 09 13:33:42 lenovo systemd[1]: pstofile.service: Succeeded.
```

My systemd service file contains the next:

```
[Unit]
Description=ps aux to file
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
ExecStart=/home/user/test/pstofile.sh
StandardInput=journal+console
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been quite long, I just want to update how I solved this.
I created a POSIX MQ, on which a daemon listens on. This daemon is in charge
of displaying to the current pty (`mq_receive()` + `write()`).
All the daemons send a message on the queue
when they start, and when they stop (with `mq_send()`)

When I start the main service, I will also start this *display* service
giving it, the pty info.